# Kibana - Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/kibana/kibana.yml'

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, centos, kibana, elk

I am new to Kibana and how its setup.

We are testing setting up Kibana on an Azure VM with Ansible playbooks, all seems to be fine but unfortunately I think during our troubleshooting we made a mistake somewhere and now the Kibana service will not start. The VM is running CentOs, the error we get is

```
Dec 07 09:47:06 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:06 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 09:47:06 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 09:47:06 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: internal/fs/utils.js:332
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: throw err;
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: ^
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/kibana/kibana.yml'
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at readYaml (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/apm-config-loader/target_node/utils/read_config.js:25:69)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at getConfigFromFiles (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/apm-config-loader/target_node/utils/read_config.js:57:18)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at loadConfiguration (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/apm-config-loader/target_node/config_loader.js:30:58)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at initApm (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/apm-config-loader/target_node/init_apm.js:18:64)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at module.exports (/usr/share/kibana/src/cli/apm.js:27:3)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/src/cli/dist.js:10:17)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) {
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: errno: -13,
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: syscall: 'open',
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: code: 'EACCES',
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: path: '/etc/kibana/kibana.yml'
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 kibana[11134]: }
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 09:47:07 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Dec 07 09:47:10 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 07 09:47:10 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:10 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: internal/fs/utils.js:332
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: throw err;
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: ^
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/kibana/kibana.yml'
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: at readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 kibana[11149]: at readYaml (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/apm-config-loader/target_node/utils/read_config.js:25:69)
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kibana.service
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
```

The permissions on the yml file are as follows

```
-rwxrwx---. 1 root kibana  130 Dec  2 14:04 kibana.keystore
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   5089 Dec  7 09:47 kibana.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root kibana  216 Nov  4 13:30 node.options
```

The systemctl status

```
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2021-12-07 09:47:14 UTC; 9min ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
  Process: 11149 ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --logging.dest="/var/log/kibana/kibana.log" --pid.file="/run/kibana/kibana.pid" (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11149 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 09:47:11 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kibana.service
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 09:47:14 es-vm1 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
```

Kibana user does exist also

```
uid=995(kibana) gid=991(kibana) groups=991(kibana)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? What should I do here? I've tried playing around with permissions on the file but the error always seems to be the same.

**Solution Update:** I was able to resolve this by doing the following chmod 2750 kibana from /etc/ directory it was an error on my part while troubleshooting on the /etc/kibana directory.

Comment: try to run using below command 

/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

chmod 755 kibana.yml

chown kibana.kibana  /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

Comment: running without sudo I get the same error ```Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/kibana/kibana.yml'``` if I run it with sudo, kibana does start up, but the service is still failing. Should I be running those commands all at the same time or one by one?

Comment: one by one with sudo user. 

1) sudo chmod 755 kibana.yml 
2) sudo  chown kibana.kibana /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
3) sudo /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

Comment: Hey, thanks for the instructions, unfortunately, we seem to still get the same error...

Comment: Off topic, @Ck_7, IMO file mode of `0755` is quite unnecessary for a configuration file. OP, have you tried the ownership of `root:kibana` and `chmod 664`?

Comment: Hello, I was able to resolve this by doing the following `chmod 2750 kibana`
from /etc/ directory it was an error on my part while troubleshooting on the /etc/kibana directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the other files in the folder have the owner as root and kibana as the group.

```
-rwxrwx---. 1 root kibana  130 Dec  2 14:04 kibana.keystore
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   5089 Dec  7 09:47 kibana.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root kibana  216 Nov  4 13:30 node.options
```

The kibana group needs to be added to kibana.yml to allow it to read the file.

`chown root:kibana kibana.yml`